# Pass ng-repeat item to a scope variable in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use an item that i get in my view and pass it to a funtion in my controller , but i don't know how to save that particular item here is my code :

The view in which I want to pass p.id

```
<tr ng-repeat=" p in projetsListe">
  <td>{{p.NomProjet}}</td>
  <td>{{calcul()}}</td>
</tr>
```

My controller function:

```
 $scope.calcul = function() {
     var coutprevu = 0;

     for (var i=0;i<$scope.task.length;i++) {
         if($scope.task[i].projet_id==p.id) { //here i need p.id from the view                            
             coutprevu+=$scope.task[i].CoutParJour*$scope.task[i].TempsPrevu;
         }
    }
    return coutprevu;    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, just pass the parameter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in projetsListe">
    <td>{{calcul(p.id)}}</td>
</tr>
```

And then recover it in the controller's function:

```
$scope.calcul = function(id) {
    console.log(id); /* Here it is! */

    var coutprevu = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.task.length; i++) {
        if($scope.task[i].projet_id == id) {
            coutprevu += $scope.task[i].CoutParJour * $scope.task[i].TempsPrevu;
        }
    }
    return coutprevu;
}
```